# How to improve bad fit of scipy's curve_fit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a histogram that is given as two lists, one representing the bins and the other the number of occurences. When plotting it, I get the blue bars in the picture below.

[image: histogramfit]

For my application, I want to fit an exponential function into my data which is the form

```
f(x) = A * exp(-B*x).
```

I tried this by utilizing the a function from the scipy package:

```
func_params, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(lambda x, A, B: A * np.exp(-B * x), 
                                          bins[:-1], 
                                          occurences)
```

The params that I get from this were used to plot the orange function in the image. I think that this is a pretty bad fit though, as the second spike is pretty much ignored completely.

**Question: is there a possibility (or option) to get a better fit?**

EDIT: a much more desirable result would look like this:

[image: betterfit]

So it basically would be a tradeoff between fitting the first and second spike.

Comment: Well such function *can* not perfectly fit this, since this is the shape of an exponential function. It does not "ignore" the second spike, you see that the orange part is skewed a bit more to the right. The point is that this is the optimal one, for *this* function. So you should try to use a different one.

Comment: You can for example play with the parameters of this plot: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+a+*+e%5E(-b*+x)+with+a+%3D+1+and+b+%3D+1 but the shape is always the same

Comment: So in short: your data is *not* of the form *A exp(-B x)*

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: thank you for your replies. I know that it is not a perfect exponential function, but I would like to have a tradeoff between the two spikes. I added an example picture in my original post. Would something like this be achieveable?

Comment: but it does not look at all like an exponential function. The second spike looks more like *A x exp(-B x)* in my opinion.

Comment: In your desired output only the first value would add 200**2 to the error so in a simple chi-square this is dominant. If you virtually treat it as an outlier by changing the cost function you might get closer to the desired result. I link I posted more than once is https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html That might help.